# Unable to install react-native-fbt in react-native 0.68(new architecture)

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I tried to install a `react-native-fbt@0.0.7` on expo sdk 45 bare workflow project or react-native project, but got failed on `ios`.

I posted a same issue on github, but no answers yet.

Any advices would be welcome and very appreciated.

### My steps to reproduce the error(with expo).

1. Install skeleton expo bare project with `expo init`.
2. Then check the build succeed on ios.
3. Install `fbt` and `react-native-fbt` as written in docs. Do `npx pod-install`
4. After then, I got error message when tried to open the project.

[image]

### Detailed error log

```
Cycle in dependencies between targets 'RNCMaskedView' and 'React-Codegen'; building could produce unreliable results.
Cycle path: RNCMaskedView → React → React-RCTAnimation → React-Codegen → RNCMaskedView
Cycle details:
→ Target 'RNCMaskedView': Libtool /Users/dean/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dooboo-fkcexugpfsphsbgzkwyvsyqbrtcl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCMaskedView/libRNCMaskedView.a normal
→ Target 'React' has target dependency on Target 'React-RCTAnimation'
→ Target 'React-RCTAnimation' has target dependency on Target 'React-Codegen'
→ Target 'React-Codegen' has compile command with input '/Users/dean/Documents/workspace/dooboolab/dooboo-native-ts/ios/build/generated/ios/react/renderer/components/ReactNativeFbtSpec/EventEmitters.cpp'
○ That command depends on command in Target 'react-native-fbt': script phase “[CP-User] Generate Specs”


Raw dependency cycle trace:

target:  ->

node: <all> ->

command: <all> ->

node: /Users/dean/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dooboo-fkcexugpfsphsbgzkwyvsyqbrtcl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCMaskedView/libRNCMaskedView.a ->

command: target-RNCMaskedView-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd429de0becebc205f4487ef585c1dcf3cba-:Debug:Libtool /Users/dean/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dooboo-fkcexugpfsphsbgzkwyvsyqbrtcl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCMaskedView/libRNCMaskedView.a normal ->

node: /Users/dean/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dooboo-fkcexugpfsphsbgzkwyvsyqbrtcl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCMaskedView.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNCMaskedView.LinkFileList ->

command: target-RNCMaskedView-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd429de0becebc205f4487ef585c1dcf3cba-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/dean/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dooboo-fkcexugpfsphsbgzkwyvsyqbrtcl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCMaskedView.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNCMaskedView.LinkFileList ->

node: <target-RNCMaskedView-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd429de0becebc205f4487ef585c1dcf3cba--entry> ->

command: Gate target-RNCMaskedView-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd429de0becebc205f4487ef585c1dcf3cba--entry ->

CYCLE POINT ->

node: <target-React-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd42091e10ab92ef02a5d90ffb84b380567b--end> ->

command: Gate target-React-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd42091e10ab92ef02a5d90ffb84b380567b--end ->

node: <target-React-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd42091e10ab92ef02a5d90ffb84b380567b--entry> ->

command: Gate target-React-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd42091e10ab92ef02a5d90ffb84b380567b--entry ->

node: <target-React-RCTAnimation-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd42fa7387fd1c471430f783250399affb7d--end> ->

command: Gate target-React-RCTAnimation-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd42fa7387fd1c471430f783250399affb7d--end ->

node: /Users/dean/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dooboo-fkcexugpfsphsbgzkwyvsyqbrtcl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTAnimation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/React-RCTAnimation.LinkFileList ->

command: target-React-RCTAnimation-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd42fa7387fd1c471430f783250399affb7d-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/dean/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dooboo-fkcexugpfsphsbgzkwyvsyqbrtcl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTAnimation.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/React-RCTAnimation.LinkFileList ->

node: <target-React-RCTAnimation-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd42fa7387fd1c471430f783250399affb7d--entry> ->

command: Gate target-React-RCTAnimation-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd42fa7387fd1c471430f783250399affb7d--entry ->

node: <target-React-Codegen-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd423e463c0b90ea125684ba7eb9113494aa--end> ->

command: Gate target-React-Codegen-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd423e463c0b90ea125684ba7eb9113494aa--end ->

node: /Users/dean/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dooboo-fkcexugpfsphsbgzkwyvsyqbrtcl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventEmitters-3826811518c4cb13b9a4b67a341d7bb9.o ->

command: target-React-Codegen-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd423e463c0b90ea125684ba7eb9113494aa-:Debug:CompileC /Users/dean/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dooboo-fkcexugpfsphsbgzkwyvsyqbrtcl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/EventEmitters-3826811518c4cb13b9a4b67a341d7bb9.o /Users/dean/Documents/workspace/dooboolab/dooboo-native-ts/ios/build/generated/ios/react/renderer/components/ReactNativeFbtSpec/EventEmitters.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler ->

node: /Users/dean/Documents/workspace/dooboolab/dooboo-native-ts/ios/build/generated/ios/react/renderer/components/ReactNativeFbtSpec/EventEmitters.cpp ->

command: target-react-native-fbt-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd425302c160cb888c82ac84a0e386ee4bac-:Debug:PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User] Generate Specs /Users/dean/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dooboo-fkcexugpfsphsbgzkwyvsyqbrtcl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-fbt.build/Script-46EB2E000100D0.sh ->

node: /Users/dean/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dooboo-fkcexugpfsphsbgzkwyvsyqbrtcl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-fbt.build/Script-46EB2E000100D0.sh ->

command: target-react-native-fbt-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd425302c160cb888c82ac84a0e386ee4bac-:Debug:WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/dean/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dooboo-fkcexugpfsphsbgzkwyvsyqbrtcl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-fbt.build/Script-46EB2E000100D0.sh ->

node: <target-react-native-fbt-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd425302c160cb888c82ac84a0e386ee4bac--entry> ->

command: Gate target-react-native-fbt-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd425302c160cb888c82ac84a0e386ee4bac--entry ->

node: <target-React-8699adb1dd336b26511df848a716bd42091e10ab92ef02a5d90ffb84b380567b--end>
```